# Node.js takes a lot of time to respond to bulk mysql update and insert operations and even repeats the add queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am a newbie to NodeJS. I am trying to do a batch update and insert operation in mysql through NodeJS. The client send a json array as a batch of object to be updated/inserted intp the mysql DB. I want node to send the response only when the last object in the batch gets added/updated. To achieve this, I am passing the `response` variable of the service to a function that checks if all the objects are transported to mysql and treated correspondingly. Please see this code below for more clarity: spare me for adopting any bad practices in my code and I would love to learn some good practices.

```
app.post(commonPath.concat("/synch"), function(req, res) {
debugger;
console.log("REQUEST : ",req.body);
var batch = req.body;
batchLength = batch.length;
if(flag){
  flag = false;
for(var i = 0 ; i < batch.length; i++) {
  console.log("batch Object is : ", batch[i]);
  var type = batch[i].type;
  var queryType = batch[i].queryType;
  var object = batch[i].data;

  /*
  check if clinic/doctor to be added/updated

  type = true | false ==> doctor object | clinic object
  queryType = true | false ==> add call | update call
  */

  if(type && queryType){
      console.log("DOCTOR ADD");
      var obj = makeDoctorObject(object);
      var msg = {};
      msg['fromBatch'] = true;
      msg['object'] = obj;
      console.log("object : ", msg);
      addDoctor(msg, res);
  }    
  else if (type && !queryType) {
      console.log("DOCTOR UPDATE");
      var obj = makeDoctorObject(object);
      obj['fromBatch'] = true;
      console.log("object : ", obj);
      updateDoctor(obj, object.id, res);
  }

  else if (!type && queryType) {
      console.log("CLINIC ADD");
      var obj = makeClinicObject(object);
      var msg = {};
      msg['fromBatch'] = true;
      msg['object'] = obj;
      console.log("object : ", msg);
      addClinic(msg, res);
  }

  else if (!type && !queryType) {
      console.log("CLINIC UPDATE");
      var obj = makeClinicObject(object);
      obj['fromBatch'] = true;
      console.log("object : ", obj);
      updateClinic(obj, object.id, res);
     }
   }
 }
});
```

Basically commonPath is a common path. This service is actually iterating through the incoming json array checking each object's type and query type and then sending the object for respective operation. Everything goes fine, but the service takes a lot of time in sending the response and moreover, it repeats the add operations. so whenever a response comes from the mysql server, I am simply appending it in a global array and with the help of a counter checking if all the objects in the batch are done processing. once the counter becomes equal to `batchLength` I am sending the response. This is the function that increments the count and sends the response when `count == batchLength`.

```js
var count = 0;
var batchLength; //set to the length of incoming json array inside the service
batchResponse = []; //json array; containing the set of resonse to each insert/update sent by mysql server
function checkBatchLength(res) {
  // debugger;
  count++;
  console.log(count, batchLength);
  if (count == batchLength) {
    var responsePayload = {};
    //this is the response to be sent to the client by the server
    responsePayload['response'] = batchResponse;
    res.send(responsePayload);
    count = 0;
    batchLength = 0;
    batchResponse = [];
    return;
  }
}
```

Please help me out. :(

Comment: How is this linked to [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: It is not. Sorry for that. I edited it. I did not see that before posting. Anyway, could I please get some help?